# SP Online 365 Document library email triggered if no item created | Daily Check

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365-developer

I have a document library in SharePoint Online 365 name Daily Reports. I need to check document is uploaded in that document library daily. If any records not added in Library an email triggered to any SharePoint group.

What is the OOTB (**preferred**) or any other way to achieve this task

Thanks,
-Taha

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft flow. Every hour you trigger a workflow and Get Items from SharePoint list and apply filter ->

> retrieve record whose date is greater than `utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')-1 day` a function in Microsoft flow. If no record found, trigger a workflow.

Reference:

1. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/FLOW-Get-Items-Filter-SharePoint-list-on-Date/td-p/85238
2. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Checking-Sharepoint-list-daily-to-see-if-create-date-is-7-days/td-p/58808

> Note: It's just a way, you need to implement flow by yourself.

Thanks